# react-native state is read-only

Tags: javascript, react-native, readonly

Following Component in react-native:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

let startValue = null // only using this to restart the counter from resetTimer() (other better approaches?)

export const NewTimer = () => {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(startValue)

  const formatedTime = () => {
    return [pad(parseInt(seconds / 60)), pad(seconds % 60)].join(':')
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => setSeconds(++seconds), 1000) // I guess this line triggers the error
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer)
    }
  }, [])

  return formatedTime
}

const pad = (num) => {
  return num.toString().length > 1 ? num : `0${num}`
}

export const resetTimer = () => {
  startValue = 0
}
```

results in Uncaught Error: "seconds" is read-only

Can anyone point where the mistake is? Thx!

Comment: React state is read only. To update it use your `setSeconds` instead of directly modifying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you do `++seconds`, you are attempting to mutate `seconds` *this render*, which isn't allowed.  I would use the setState callback to get the current value, and just do `seconds + 1`, which will accomplish the same thing:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const timer = setInterval(() => setSeconds((seconds) => seconds + 1), 1000)
  return () => {
    clearInterval(timer)
  }
}, [])
```